# Applying a function to switch the position of rows repeatedly

Tags: r

I am currently working on a super long dataframe in R that looks like this

| Year | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1912 | 0.5 |
| 1912 | 0.6 |
| 1913 | 0.2 |
| 1913 | 0.3 |
| 1914 | 1.4 |
| 1915 | 1.2 |

And I need to switch the position every two rows so that it looks like this

| Year | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1912 | 0.6 |
| 1912 | 0.5 |
| 1913 | 0.3 |
| 1913 | 0.2 |
| 1914 | 1.2 |
| 1915 | 1.4 |

I feel so confused about if there is anything I can do to achieve that or I need to write the function by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by `Year` and `rev`erse the 'Value' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Year) %>%
    mutate(Value = rev(Value)) %>%
    ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1912L, 1912L, 1913L, 1913L, 1914L, 1915L
), Value = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 1.4, 1.2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```